# Multiplying column by weight in another table requiring a second select and summing in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I think this is a pretty common request to do in SQL but simply cannot find a good 'SQL' way to do this. From a result of one query, I want to multiply a series of returned values by a weighting factor that is found in another table and sum the total. I can do this in a language by iterating through, but how can I do this in SQL directly?

So the result of Query 1 might be:

```
10, 20, 40, 70, 90 ...
```

from `Select Values from Table1;`

Table1

```
VID   Value
1     10
2     20
.
.
```

Table2

```
ID   Weight VID
1     0.1    1
2     0.01   2
.
.
```

and the weights are...

```
0.1, 0.01, 10, 0.05, 4.0

So the result is 10*0.1 + 20*0.01 + 40*10 + 70*0.05 + 90*4.0 + ..
```

What is the correct formalism for this? I don't mind multiple queries, as this is debug code to go alongside the more programmatic/language way of doing this with a record set.

Comment: You need to show detail about how the numbers are related to each other.  Can you show the code that generates the results?

Comment: fyi-- Doing this on the SQL Server, as in the answer by @Jas, will probably be faster than in procedural code. That's especially compared to looping through a recordset, and having to select all the data first and then doing your procedural code.  (of course, if it is a very small data set, you might not notice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(t1.value * t2.weight) 
from t1
join t2 on t1.vid = t2.vid
```